# Short story about a boy who finds a caterpillar with a human face

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

When I was 12 or 13, in 1985-86, I read a short story, set in England, about a boy who finds a caterpillar with a human face in his garden. I think he takes it to his room and feeds it. I have the impression that his home life was unhappy, that his parents were separated or separating. At any rate, he finds comfort and diversion in feeding and looking at this creature, which is green, with green hair and green teeth.

The creature wasn't endearing or cute. It was strange and uncanny and sad, though the boy found solace in it. I found the idea of a perfectly formed human face on a caterpillar weird and disturbing.

One day, the boy discovers the creature gone. He goes to the garden in the hope of finding it. He finds his dad's Wellington boots and picks one up. He looks at the sole and sees the squashed remains of the caterpillar, its green human face and green human teeth evident. The mixture of horror and sadness I felt left an impression on me and I have looked for this story for years.

Does anyone else remember this story? I don't think I dreamt it, due to the fact it clearly concludes as a story arc, however dreadfully. I have a feeling the story may have been in an anthology edited or containing a contribution by Roald Dahl.

Comment: Interesting idea esp. because I there are insects that simulate faces/eyes to help avoid predators. If spiders can adapt to imitate ants fairly well, perhaps an insect with a human-looking face really exists. There is also the story Mimic which is tangentially related.